# custom config variable with pytest

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, pyramid

AIM - I am trying to pass a config variable 'db_str' to my pytest script (test_script.py)

The db_str variable is defined in development.ini

I have tried using command

```
pytest -c development.ini regression_tests/test_script.py
```

But it didn't work

Error

```
>       conn_string = config['db_string']
        KeyError: 'db_string'
```

I tried using conftest.py, but didn't work

```
#contest.py code
import pytest

def pytest_addoption(parser):
   parser.addoption("--set-db_st", 
   action="store",help="host='localhost' dbname='xyz' user='portaladmin'")

@pytest.fixture
def db_str(request):
   return request.config.getoption("--set-db_str")
```

Pytest code

```
from S4M_pyramid.modelimport MyModel
from S4M_pyramid.lib.deprecated_pylons_globals import config

import subprocess

config['db_str'] = db_str
def test_get_dataset_mapping_id():
   result = MyModel.get_dataset_mapping_id()
   assert len(result) >1
```

How can I pass variable 'db_str' from development.ini or any other ini file to pytest script

Comment: You're using 4 different spelling of the name: `--set-db_st`, `--set-db_str`, `db_str` and `db_string`. Can you choose one spelling and use it everywhere in the code?

Answer (score 3):

The logic is the fillowing:

1. Define CLI argument that will be used to pass information about environment/config file
2. Get CLI argument value in pytest fixture
3. Parse config file
4. Use parsed config in `get_database_string` fixture to get database connection string
5. Use `get_database_string` fixture in your tests to get connection string

**conftest.py**

```
import os

from configparser import ConfigParser

# in root of the project there is file project_paths.py
# with the following code ROOT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
import project_paths 


def pytest_addoption(parser):
    """Pytest hook that defines list of CLI arguments with descriptions and default values

    :param parser: pytest specific argument
    :return: void
    """
    parser.addoption('--env', action='store', default='development',
                     help='setup environment: development')



@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def get_database_string(get_config):
    """Fixture that returns db_string

    :param get_config: fixture that returns ConfigParser object that access 
    to config file
    :type: ConfigParser

    :return: Returns database connection string
    :rtype: str
    """
    return get_config['<section name>']['db_string']


@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def get_config(request):
    """Functions that reads and return  ConfigParser object that access 
    to config file

    :rtype: ConfigParser
    """
    environment = request.config.getoption("--env")
    config_parser = ConfigParser()
    file_path = os.path.join(project_paths.ROOT_DIR, '{}.ini'.format(environment))
    config_parser.read(file_path)
    return config_parser
```

**test_file.py**

```
import pytest

def test_function(get_database_string)
    print(get_database_string)
```

`>>> <data base string from development.ini>`

Comment: can u please help me with following error that I am getting


    environment = request.config.getoption("--env")NameError: name 'request' is not defined . in **  def get_config():
        """Functions that reads and return  ConfigParser object that access
        to config file
    
        :rtype: ConfigParser
        """
>       environment = request.config.getoption("--env")**

Comment: Also I am getting error with return get_config.get('db_string') 

    TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'option'

Comment: @ghanishtnagpal I updated code snippet in my answer. I was missing `request` as param in `get_config fixture`. as for your second comment I also updated code. So in order to be able to get data from config you should do something like `config['section name']['db_string']`

Answer (score 3):

As described on [pytest_addoption](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#initialization-hooks):

add options:

> To add command line options, call parser.addoption(...).
>
> To add ini-file values call ***parser.addini***(...).

get options:

> Options can later be accessed through the config object, respectively:
>
> config.getoption(name) to retrieve the value of a command line option.
>
> ***config.getini(name)*** to retrieve a value read from an ini-style file.

**conftest.py:**

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addini('foo', '')
```

**test.py:**

```
def test_func(request):
    request.config.getini('foo')
```